# Databricks connector for Dynamics 365 Sales data

Tags: azure-databricks, dynamics-365

Can someone let me know if a connector / library to Dynamics Sales Data exists for Databricks.

There is library provided by a private company called CData here

https://www.cdata.com/kb/tech/d365sales-jdbc-apache-spark.rst

However, I was wondering if there was a existing connector / library provided by another 3rd Party

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/data-sources/), below is the list of connectors.

[image]

To connect to Dynamic 365 you can use API in Azure Databricks. For more information follow this [article](https://dynamics-chronicles.com/article/azure-databricks-tutorial-dynamics-365-cds-use-cases) by Amaury Veron